# jquery / css background change not showing up in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, background

I'm changing the background of the body with jquery (when a link is hovered). It works perfectly in FF and IE but Chrome(v37) doesn't change the background.

I tried getting it to work with the JS console in chrome but even there it doesn't change the BG.

See this example: It doesn't change the (complete) BG unless the window is resized. In my live website it doesn't change the BG at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/vk503agt/

```
    $("a").mouseover(function (){

    var bg = $("body").css(["background-image","background-repeat","background-attachment","background-size","background-position"]);

    var bgimage = bg["background-image"];

    bg["background-image"]=bgimage.replace(/http.+jpg/,"http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs17/f/2007/129/7/4/Stock_032__by_enchanted_stock.jpg");

    $("body").css({"background-image":bg["background-image"],"background-repeat":bg["background-repeat"],"background-attachment":bg["background-attachment"],"background-size":bg["background-size"],"background-position":bg["background-position"]});

});
```

Note: It is necessary to read and write all used background properties or they will go missing when only changing "background-image" with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in **display:inline** of the body.
I think that the inline in background have not sense.
Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks that works in the example but didn't in my live website. I found the problem tough: Chrome can't handle special characters like space or braces in the source path.